# Game of Life - What is with this algorithm

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm

I have created a simplified game of life.

This is my cell where the actual stuff happens:

```
class Cell
{
    public Cell(MainWindow correspondingMainWindow){
        this.mainWindow = correspondingMainWindow;
    }

    public bool excluded;

    public Boolean Occupied { get; set; }

    public Control correspondingPanel;

    private int[] coordinates;

    private MainWindow mainWindow;

    public int[] Coordinates
    {
        get { return this.coordinates; }
        set { 
            if(value.Length != 2) 
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            else if(value[0] < 0 || value [1] < 0
                     || value[0] > Settings.FIELDWIDTH 
                     || value[1] > Settings.FIELDHEIGHT)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            else{
                correspondingPanel = mainWindow.FieldArea.Controls
                         .Find(String.Format("panel{0}_{1}", value[0], value[1]), true)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
                this.coordinates = value;
            }
        }

    }

    //Surrounding Cells in the 3x3 around the current cell
    //this is to speed up the updating as soon as the algorithm runs on many cells
    public Cell Top { get; set; }
    public Cell TopRight { get; set; }
    public Cell Right { get; set; }
    public Cell BotRight { get; set; }
    public Cell Bot { get; set; }
    public Cell BotLeft { get; set; }
    public Cell Left { get; set; }
    public Cell TopLeft { get; set; }

    public void die()
    {
        this.Occupied = false;
        this.correspondingPanel.BackColor = Color.Beige;
    }

    public void populate()
    {
        this.Occupied = true;
        this.correspondingPanel.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
    }
}
```

Here is the algorithm in question:

```
//should return true if there were any changes to any "living" state
bool Algorithm.runOver(Cell target)
{
    if (target.Occupied && !target.excluded)
    {
        target.Right.populate();
        target.Left.populate();
        target.Top.populate();
        target.Bot.populate();

        target.Right.excluded = true;
        target.Left.excluded = true;
        target.Top.excluded = true;
        target.Bot.excluded = true;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

excluded and already run are resetted to false everytime the algorithm has finished running all cells once. this is to prevent the call of walkOver() on a Cell updated in this walk.

now when i take my cell in the top left edge of my field (which continues like the simple snake field), mark it and run the algorithm, it stops changes after the first run through.

it actually updates the Cell in the designed way, but then just stops.

i save my cells into a static List in Program (i know i shouldn't but it's the easiest way to go until it works correctly). the cells have some panels to match. these panels are in a GroupBox named FieldArea. they are generated dynamically on the basis of some static constant settings (that you see in the set validation for coordinates).

I am sure the cells match to the panels correctly. this problem seems to occur in the diagonal through the FieldArea from top left (0,0) to bottom right. any other starting point works correctly. somehow when a larger amount of cells is coming from "the top" the cells form a border on the top and left edge of the field.

Question now is: what am i doing wrong? Why is my field not working correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must keep two copies of your "world", beacuse one must remain unchanged while you are applying the rules. If you apply the rules to one only world, this will result in a mixed configuration where some cells will have an old state, while others will already have the new one.

Therefore do something like this:

```
private Cell[,] activeWorld = new Cell[w,h];
private Cell[,] hiddenWorld = new Cell[w,h];

Populate(activeWorld);
while (true) {
    Display(activeWorld);
    ApplyRules(activeWorld, hiddenWorld);

    // Swap worlds
    var temp = activeWorld;
    activeWorld = hiddenWorld;
    hiddenWorld = temp;
}
```

The method `ApplyRules` must read the cells from 'activeWorld' and write the result to `hiddenWorld`.

---

UPDATE: Your actual design seems to be over-designed to me. A simple 2-d Boolean array telling whether a cell is occupied or not should be sufficient. Don't start with optimizations. This will most probably result in a complicated, hardly readable and faulty code. Instead focus your attention to the algorithm and to a good code structure. If later, you experience performance problems, analyze the problems and apply appropriate optimizations. In > 95% of the cases the problem is not related to coding details and algorithms but to I/O. In the case of this game, displaying the cells will probably take much more time than the application of the rules. And probably it will be too fast anyway and you will have to add a pause in the game loop.

Don't try to optimize away the logic of getting the indexes of the surrounding cells. It's not worth the pain.

One good way of solving the margin cells problem is to wrap the world around. Make things going out of sight on the right side reappear on the left side, and so on. Use the modulo operation (%) for this. `x % N` always yields a value in the range `0 ... N-1`. You can get the coordinates of the 3 x 3 cells like this given an x and a y coordinate:

```
for (int dx = -1; dx <= +1; dx++) {
    int i = (x + dx + Width) % Width;
    for (int dy = -1; dy <= +1; dy++) {
        int j = (y + dy + Height) % Height;
        bool occupied = world[i, j];
        ...
    }
}
```

The `+ Width` and `+ Height` ensure that we always have positive values.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, as promised here is my personal win-of-the week:

the above mentioned algorithm was "faulty"

unfortunately I was excluding cells, that weren't changed. and as I walked through the List from the "top left" the error showed up there.

i moved the exclusion to the die() and populate() functions.

```
public void die(){
    this.Occupied = false;
    this.correspondingPanel.BackColor = Color.Beige;
    this.excluded = true;
}
```

then i also had to make sure the loop gets correctly broken:

```
public Algorithm.walkOver(Cell target)
{
   if (target.Occupied && !target.excluded)
   {
       bool b = true;

   //if there could no changes be made, we also have to return there were no changes... 
   //else the while loop continues forever and we lose the process :(
       if (target.Right.Occupied && target.Left.Occupied 
           && target.Bot.Occupied && target.Top.Occupied)
       b = false;

       if(!target.Right.Occupied)
           target.Right.populate();

       if (!target.Left.Occupied)
           target.Left.populate();

       if (!target.Top.Occupied)
          target.Top.populate();

       if (!target.Bot.Occupied)
          target.Bot.populate();

       return b;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I also moved the reset to the start of the while loop, as "chosing" a cell was excluding it.

Comment: If your problem is sloved, please, forget my comment.